# Can't assign string literals to array of characters in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals

I'm trying to assign string literals to array of characters.

This code works fine

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
    char* name;
};

struct student s[2];

void main()
{
    s[0].name = "jason";
    s[1] = s[0];

    printf("%s%s", s[0].name, s[1].name);

    s[1].name = "fedin";

    printf("%s%s", s[0].name, s[1].name);
}
```

But this code isn't working:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct item {
  char* itemName;
  int quantity;
  float price;
  float amount;
};

void readItem(item* const p) {
  printf("Please enter item name. \n");
  fgets(p->itemName, 50, stdin);
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p->itemName); i++)
  {
    if (p->itemName[i] == '\n') {
      p->itemName[i] = NULL;
    }
  }

  printf("Please enter the quantity. \n");
  scanf_s("%d", &p->quantity);

  printf("Please enter the price. \n");
  scanf_s("%f", &p->price);
}

void print(item* const p) {
  printf("Item Name: %s \n", p->itemName);
  printf("Quantity: %i \n", p->quantity);
  printf("Price: %.4f \n", p->price);

  p->amount = (p->quantity) * (p->price);
  printf("Amount: %.4f \n", p->amount);
}

int main(void) {
  struct item item1;

  item1.itemName = "SDfsd";

  item1.quantity = 0;
  item1.price = 0.0;
  item1.amount = 0.0;

  struct item* itemP = &item1;

  readItem(itemP);
  print(itemP);

  free(itemP->itemName);
  itemP->itemName = NULL;

  return 0;

}
```

The error that the compiler gave me:

```
Error (active)  E0513 a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "char *" Structure Pointers and Functions  F:\Mohamed Taha\Codes\C Programming\C Programming For Beginners\vs\Structure Pointers and Functions\Structure Pointers and Functions\mian.cpp 41
```

I tried to ask ChatGPT first, as usual, but it didn't provide me with any explanation. It says that the error is because string literals are in read-only memory, so you cannot write to them, but that didn't make any sense because the first code works.

Note: Both pieces of code run on the same compiler.

Comment: The dismaying part of learning C is when you first realize that C has no proper support for strings -- rather, it has support for arrays-of-char, and it has support for pointers, and C programmers are expected to cobble together string semantics from those as best they can.  :/

Comment: Based on your error message you are writing C code, but compiling it as C++ code. This will add an extra variable into figuring out where your problems lie.

Comment: Note also that your first example doesn't actually try to write to a string literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `struct item` is not a `typedef`, the function parameter should be prepended with a `struct` keyword; the `item` is unrecognized otherwise.

```
void readItem(struct item* const p)
void print(struct item* const p)
```

Also, note that `NULL` expands to `((void *)0)`, which is not a `char`. If you want to set a null-terminator, then you need to use `'\0'` or a `0` here:

```
p->itemName[i] = NULL; // Should be = '\0' or 0
```

And yes, C is not going to allocate memory for the `itemName` itself, so use `malloc`:

```
p->itemName = (void *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
printf("Please enter item name. \n");
.
.
```

---

Now, it runs well:

```
Please enter item name. 
test
Please enter the quantity. 
3
Please enter the price. 
2
Item Name: test 
Quantity: 3
Price: 2.0000
Amount: 6.0000
```

Comment: `p->itemName = (void *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);` Two things: 1) No need to cast the return from `malloc()` (especially not to `void*`) and 2) `sizeof(char)` is, by definition in the language, `1` so need not appear in code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 You are right, but I know, and I did it on purpose for the sake of clarity in code.

Comment: Cluttering code with redundant text does the exact opposite of improving clarity.

Comment: In fact, thinking about how that line would look without the clutter would make the _magic number_ **50** stand out as a bad idea... Don't use magic numbers in code...

Comment: You need the cast only if you do like the OP, and compile C with a C++ compiler. That does not increase clarity!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change read-only memory, which is what you end-up with by using a string literal:

```
item1.itemName = "SDfsd";
```

Declaring a variable of the type pointer to char (char *) does not reserve memory for the string (actually there are no strings in C, only array of char). So you need to allocate memory, for example:

```
item1.itemName = (char*) malloc(100);
```

Another problem is that you confuse NULL, which is a null pointer with the value 0, and the null character. You should use

```
p->itemName[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: This is `C` so you should not cast the result of `malloc`.